# Is there an R version of Rstudio's 'find in files'?

Tags: r, rstudio

I love Rstudio's 'find in files' function, where you can search for text in all files in a specified directory, but I hate the way to specify the directory to search and types of files, you have to click and point, urgh!

Does anyone know of a simple way of doing this in R console?

Comment: just use grep on unix or findstr on windows, called through the `system` command of R?

Comment: You can also try to use notepad++, I think they have a similar functionality

Comment: try the **findInFiles** package

Answer (score 4):

```r
fif <- function(what, where=".", in_files="\\.[Rr]$", recursive = TRUE,
                ignore.case = TRUE) {

  fils <- list.files(path = where, pattern = in_files, recursive = recursive)

  found <- FALSE

  file_cmd <- Sys.which("file")

  for (fil in fils) {

    if (nchar(file_cmd) > 0) {
      ftype <- system2(file_cmd, fil, TRUE)
      if (!grepl("text", ftype)[1]) next
    }

    contents <- readLines(fil)

    res <- grepl(what, contents, ignore.case = ignore.case)
    res <- which(res)

    if (length(res) > 0) {

      found <-  TRUE

      cat(sprintf("%s\n", fil), sep="")
      cat(sprintf(" % 4s: %s\n", res, contents[res]), sep="")

    }

  }

  if (!found) message("(No results found)")

}
```

Running

```
> fif("map")
```

in the console in the top level of my `gdns` package results in:

```
R/dkim.r
   11: #'   purrr::map_df(dkim_rec, .parse_dkim)
   21: #'       purrr::map_df(~{
R/gdns-package.r
   29: #' @importFrom purrr safely map map_df %||% %>%
R/gdns.r
  102:   results <- map(entities, gdns::query, type=type, edns_client_subnet=edns_client_subnet)
  103:   map_df(results, "Answer")
R/spf.r
   11:   purrr::map(spf_rec, .split_spf)
   76:   purrr::map(split_spf(spf_rec), function(x) {
   84:   purrr::map(split_spf(spf_rec), function(x) {
   92:   purrr::map(split_spf(spf_rec), function(x) {
  100:   purrr::map(split_spf(spf_rec), function(x) {
  108:   purrr::map(split_spf(spf_rec), function(x) {
```

in the console.

If no files are found matching `what` it tells you so:

```r
> fif("python")
(No results found)
```

Keep the function in your `~/.Rprofile` and it'll be in all non-vanilla R sessions.

Comment: I'm trying on windows and it doesn't work, I think the problem may be in the Sys.which command? Trying to debug here, but if you have a quick solution in the meantime I would appreciated it. Sorry, I should have said in which system I intended to use it, my bad.
Thanks for the answer though, the function looks awesome!

Comment: Try installing https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/installer.html first then try the function.

Comment: To search in other than the current directory (a non-default `where` in the function) I needed to add `full.names = TRUE` to the call to `list.files`.  Otherwise, great function, thanks.

Comment: This is excellent - I'm working in a niche situation where RStudio's 'find in files' doesn't work and this works a treat!

Answer (score 1):

I've just done a package for finding a pattern in some files: [findInFiles](https://github.com/stla/findInFiles) (not finished yet, but soon).

The pattern to search for is a regular expression. You can control the depth of the search and there is an option for case-sensitivity. Results are displayed in the RStudio viewer (actually this is a `htmlwidget`).

It requires the `grep` command-line utility, which is always available in Linux platforms; on Windows I think it is installed when you install `git`.

```
remotes::install_github("stla/findInFiles")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This function will return the file path and the line where the pattern was identified.

```
find_in_files <- function(path, pattern){
  path |> 
    fs::dir_ls(recurse = TRUE, type = "file", regexp = "(\\.[rR])$") |> 
    purrr::map(~grep(pattern, readLines(.x, warn = FALSE), value = TRUE)) |> 
    purrr::keep(~length(.x) > 0)
}
```