# How can I search my snippets files in RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio

Snippets files are not searchable as opened in RStudio, and as I have lots of snippets I often need to search through them, particularly my lesser used snippets. Is there an efficient way to search snippets within RStudio?

Answer (score 1):

Since all snippets are saved by default in ~/.R/snippets, they can be viewed by executing

```
ls ~/.R/snippets
```

I then wrote this convenience function so I can open and search my snippets in RStudio:

```
snippet_search <- function(language=c('r', 'sql', 'python', 'markdown'), dir = '~/.R/snippets'){
    file <- glue::glue('{dir}/{language}.snippets')
    file.edit(file)
}

snippet_search('r')
```

Comment: and extend to [text therein](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45502010/is-there-an-r-version-of-rstudios-find-in-files) perhaps.

Comment: On my system the snippets are  saved in Windows: %appdata%\RStudio\snippets

Comment: What is `~` supposed to mean? A path?

Comment: The line `ls ~/.R/snippets` does nto work on a command prompt